# Two update queries with Exist reserved word Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, exists

Hello I am trying to run this update query:

```
UPDATE Employee_Table
SET Employee_Table.First_Name =
    (
        SELECT
            [Employee_Table].[Full_Name]
            ,LEFT([Full_Name], InStr([Full_Name], " ") - 1) AS First_Name
        FROM [Employee_Table]
    )
    ,Employee_Table.Last_Name =
    (
        SELECT
            [Employee_Table].[Last_Name]
            ,mid([Full_Name], InStr([Full_Name], " ") + 1) AS Last_Name
        FROM [Employee_Table]
    )
WHERE (((Employee_Table.First_Name) IS NULL) AND ((Employee_Table.Last_Name) IS NULL));
```

However, I get a message stating that says the following:
"I have written a sub-query that can return more than one field without using the Exists Reserved word."

I built the query within access and it put most of the SQL code there.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you want to extract the first and last names from the full name field and store them in the same row.

```
UPDATE Employee_Table
SET
    First_Name = Left(Full_Name, InStr(Full_Name, " ") - 1),
    Last_Name = Mid(Full_Name, InStr(Full_Name, " ") + 1)
WHERE
        First_Name Is Null
    AND Last_Name Is Null;
```